Magento 2.4 cataloginventory_stock_item purpose
We are not using the Default Magento stock /source due to limitations with assigning multiple sources to the default stock.
We have created a new stock (Website Stock) and assigned 3 sources relating to our stores.
We have cleared out the inventory_source_item table of all references to the 'default' source. This basically unassigned the default source from all products (or so we thought).
These 3 sources may have stock, and if they do not, they remain listed in the admin grid. EG
    Source 00 = 0 qty
    Source 01 = 10 qty
    Source 03 = 100 qty

When we update a product/reindex, the old 'Default' source is applied still, and shows in the admin grid/product page (Though this does not impact the website stock levels, becuase the website is not set to use it).
We found that it was pulling the data from the cataloginventory_stock_item table.
First question.
**1. What is the purpose of these tables (cataloginventory_) over the inventory_ tables? **
The cataloginventory_stock_item table only had references to the default stock, and not our new Website Stock.
Second question.
2. Why does the cataloginventory_stock_item table only contain data for the default stock that we are no longer wanting to use. Why does it not list data for the new "Website Stock"?
We deleted a row for a product from this table. I deleted the reference from the inventory_source_item table for the same product (So default stock/source does not show in admin grid/product page for that product again). Now when we update/reindex, Default still gets applied, but with a quantity of zero.
Third question.
3. Is it safe to truncate and ignore the cataloginventory_stock_item table?
Fourth question.
4. How can we stop the old unused Default stock being displayed in the admin grid/product edit page, even though its zero (or will be for every product if we truncate cataloginventory_stock_item)?
